# Can Wonder Woman die?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

Obviously major spoilers ahead, please don't read if you haven't seen the movie.

We are told towards the end of the movie that Diana is the god-killer, since apparently only a god can kill another god, and with what we saw in the movie, it would appear that Ares is dead. We are also told that Ares killed all the other gods. So since Diana is a god/demigod, is anything able to kill her now?

To be clear, I am asking with the assumption that Ares is actually dead and does not somehow come back to life.

Comment: You won't find out until sequel #8.

Comment: Even taking all that at face value, it sounds like suicide would work.

Comment: If we have to take the "only a god can kill another god", then she had not really been very fair to Superman in Batman V Superman. On the other side, gods like Ares and Diana are clearly not omniscient nor omnipotent, so there are probably other pantheons they are not aware of.

Comment: *and does not somehow come back to life.* Have you ever read comics before? - "can" asks for speculation. *has she ever died* is the only valid way to ask this question on SE, IMO. If we could ask for lists here, I'd ask for which super heroes *haven't* died...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would appear that he's dead, but this is a comic universe; Ares is only dead as long as his death is convenient for story purposes.

We do know from the movie that all the other gods are "dead", because Ares killed them all. Both Hippolyta and Ares confirmed this. Logically that means that yes, Diana can be killed too. But of course "dead" in a comic universe doesn't necessarily mean gone forever.

If you are worried about the lack of remaining gods to do the job, I wouldn't. Just because she's the last of Zeus's children doesn't mean there aren't other gods running around. Additionally, Ares wasn't exactly in a position to stand there and rattle off a long list of the exact conditions that would be required to kill either of them. He was just saying **it takes more than the little bit of power a human or Amazonian might have access to**. There's no reason to believe another type of hugely-powered entity, like [Doomsday in BvS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_(comics)#Film), wouldn't be capable of doing it.

Answer (score 13):

The "only Gods can kill Gods" might be referring to power levels, not necessarily real God status.

In the comics she is killed a bunch of times. Neron (a demon) kills her, the Anti-Monitor reverts her aging backwards and eventually into clay, and so on.

It is only logical to assume her future enemies in the movies will be up to her level of power (even if they are not Gods).

Comment: Right. This is what I was trying to say, but in sentences rather than paragraphs.

Comment: @T.E.D. says the guy who actually wrote one paragraph per each of CyberClaw's sentences.  If you're going to comment on competing answers, it helps to at least be accurate.  :)

Comment: @TOOGAM - That was kinda my point. I'm someone who highly values succinctness. I was explaining an upvote.